Issue with Redirecting After Successful Login and Signup in Next.js + Firebase with JWT Authentication
I’m using Next.js with Firebase Authentication and JWT to build a login/signup flow. Everything seems to be working fine — users can register and login successfully, and JWT tokens are generated without any issues. However, after a successful login or signup, users are not being redirected to the dashboard. Instead, they stay on the same page (either the login or signup page).
No errors related to authentication are showing up in the console, and I can verify that the JWT is being created and returned correctly from the server. The issue seems to be with how cookies are being set or handled.
1. Login Page (login.tsx)
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import firebase from "@/firebase/firebaseConfig"; // Firebase configuration
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();  // To programmatically redirect

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        firebase.auth(),
        email,
        password
      );

      const token = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();

      // Send token to backend for JWT generation and set cookie
      const response = await fetch("/api/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ token }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Assuming the backend sets the JWT cookie here
        router.push("/dashboard"); // Redirect after successful login
      } else {
        console.log("Failed to login: ", await response.json());
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error logging in: ", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

2. Backend Login API (pages/api/auth/login.ts)
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { verifyIdToken } from "@/utils/firebaseAdmin";
import { generateJWTToken } from "@/utils/jwt";
import cookie from "cookie";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { token } = req.body;

    try {
      // Verify Firebase token
      const decodedToken = await verifyIdToken(token);

      // Generate JWT
      const jwtToken = generateJWTToken({
        _id: decodedToken.uid,
        email: decodedToken.email,
      });

      // Set JWT in cookies
      res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie",
        cookie.serialize("token", jwtToken, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
          path: "/",
        })
      );

      res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful" });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to authenticate" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
  }
}

3. Dashboard Page (dashboard.tsx)
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { cookies } from "next/headers"; // Using next/headers for cookie retrieval

const Dashboard = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = cookies().get("token")?.value; // Attempt to read the token from cookies
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/login"); // Redirect to login if token doesn't exist
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>Welcome to the dashboard!</div>;
};

export default Dashboard;


What’s Working:

Firebase authentication works perfectly.
JWT tokens are generated on the server-side.
The API returns a 200 status when login/signup is successful, and the backend sets the cookie.

After successful login/signup:

The cookie is not being set on the client-side, which is why the dashboard is not accessible after login.
The cookies().get("token") is returning undefined on the dashboard, so the user is being redirected to the login page.

